# regex to match two characters and one equal operator

Tags: regex

I'm reading a file.

In that file I'm using row separator to split file. But in file the row separators are not constant.

Here is my file example.

```
CN=100
adshnxhndxghdngfhdsfs

CN=200
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew

XN=300
jskhd sa

ZP=400
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew

XX=500
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
```

Any my row separators in above file are like these CN=, ZP=, XX=, XN= There can be more because its gonna be very big file.

What regex I can use to figure out my row separators of pattern like these(CN=, ZP=, XX=, XN=)

Comment: ^[A-Z]{2}=     (Assuming you want two capital letters then equal sign at beginning of a line.)

Comment: `^[A-Z]{2}=[0-9]+$` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as

```
^\w{2}=\d+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jVequp/2) (mind the multiline modifier and tell us your programming language, though!)

Comment: ...before equal operator only two character should be there as an row separator pattern. Do you think so this will be okay ?

Comment: @Shannin: Updated the answer.